# How to use substrings in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, substring

I'd like to plot a datafile using substrings from a column. My data file contains data in the format

```
1 (15, 3): dX: -1.619, dY: 3.315, dXSc: 0.981, dYSc: 0.993
2 ( 4,16): dX: -0.540, dY: -0.540, dXSc: 0.992, dYSc: 0.977
...
```

and I'd like to plot the numbers between the brackets `(x,y)` as `y` against `x`, something like:

```
plot "data.dat" u substr(($2),7,8 ):substr(($2),10,11)
```

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 5):

Doing this properly with gnuplot is a bit tricky, because gnuplot doesn't allow specifying an arbitrary format as input. Usually, the best way would be to use an external tool to extract the data for you and feed the resulting file to gnuplot (this could be also done on-the-fly using the syntax (`plot '< script data.dat'...`).

However, in your case there is a hack to get it working with gnuplot following the next steps:

- Use `set datafile separator ':'` to have the information of both `x` and `y` in a single column.
- Use `strstrt` to determine the start and end string positions of the `x` and `y` values.

  For the `x`-value this would be

  ```
  substr(s, strstrt(s, "(")+1, strstrt(s, ",")-1)
  ```
- Add `0.0` to the resulting substrings to have them implicitely converted to real values.

A complete script, which works with your example data is

```
set datafile separator ":"
get_x(c) = 0.0 + substr(strcol(c), strstrt(strcol(c), "(") + 1, strstrt(strcol(c), ",") - 1)
get_y(c) = 0.0 + substr(strcol(c), strstrt(strcol(c), ",") + 1, strstrt(strcol(c), ")") - 1)

plot 'data.dat' using (get_x(1)):(get_y(1)) with points pt 7 ps 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, 
unfortunately I get the error message: 
"internal error: substring range operator applied to non-STRING type"

My datafile looks like this:

   1 (15, 3): dX: -1.619, dY:  3.315, dXSc: 0.981, dYSc: 0.993
   2 ( 4,16): dX: -0.540, dY: -0.540, dXSc: 0.992, dYSc: 0.977
   ...

and I'd like to plot the numbers between the brackets (x,y) as y against x
with: plot "data.dat" using (substr(strcol(2),2,3)):(substr(strcol(2),5,6))

What could be the reason for the error ?

Thanks

Comment: Finally found time to try this, and it's magic: it works. Thank you so much !  Where can I find info about commands like get_(x) ?  Regards

Comment: Great :) Sticking such functions together require more detailed knowledge about gnuplot's data handling. Gnuplot usually is the wrong tool for doing such parsing, although in some cases like yours it can be done. In many cases it's better to have an external script, e.g. in python or any other language, which does the actual parsing and passes the resulting data to gnuplot, like `plot '< python script.py data.dat'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records: for gnuplot 4.6, Christoph's answer is certainly a good way to go.

However, at the time of OP's question, gnuplot 5.0.0 was already available.
gnuplot 5.0.0 (Jan 2015) has the option to define multiple datafile separators, check `help datafile separator`. With this, the task simplifies to:

**Script:**

```
### extract numbers between various separators
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1 (15, 3): dX: -1.619, dY: 3.315, dXSc: 0.981, dYSc: 0.993
2 ( 4,16): dX: -0.540, dY: -0.540, dXSc: 0.992, dYSc: 0.977
3 ( 1.5,10.5): dX: -0.540, dY: -0.540, dXSc: 0.992, dYSc: 0.977
EOD

set datafile separator "(,)"

plot $Data u 2:3 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Actually, you could also set 4 separators, i.e. `"(,):"` and split your table and write it into a new "clean" table `$DataNew`. You have to be careful which columns you select, here it would be `1:2:3:6:8:10:12`.

**Script:**

```
### extract numbers between various separators, get "clean" table
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1 (15, 3): dX: -1.619, dY: 3.315, dXSc: 0.981, dYSc: 0.993
2 ( 4,16): dX: -0.540, dY: -0.540, dXSc: 0.992, dYSc: 0.977
3 ( 1.5,10.5): dX: -0.540, dY: -0.540, dXSc: 0.992, dYSc: 0.977
EOD

set datafile separator "(,):"
set table $DataNew
    plot $Data u 1:2:3:6:8:10:12 w table
unset table
set datafile separator    # set to default

print $DataNew
# plot whatever you like...
### end of script
```

**Result:**

`$DataNew`

```
 1       15      3       -1.619   3.315  0.981   0.993
 2       4       16      -0.54   -0.54   0.992   0.977
 3       1.5     10.5    -0.54   -0.54   0.992   0.977
```